# build AdMob Interstitial ad again after 60 seconds

Tags: android, firebase, admob

Currently, I am using the code which is displaying AdMob Interstitial ad after 20 seconds and when the ad is closed I want to show another ad after 60 seconds, this is the code currently I am using for the first ad to load after 20 seconds

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                interAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
                interAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                        .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
                        .build();
                interAd.loadAd(adRequest);
                interAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override

                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        interAd.show();
                    }
                });

                interAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
                    Log.i("Ads", "onAdClosed");
                }
        });

            }
        } , 20000);
```

i have tried this method from AdMob tutorial it load the ads but after every second

```
interAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        // Load the next interstitial.
        interAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }

});
```

Comment: Remove or mask your AdUnitId :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should attach you Ad's lifecycle to your Activity's lifecycle so you can start/stop showing adds just when your app is visible to the user.

Create a global variables for you Ad and Handler

```
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        // Wait 60 seconds
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 60*1000);

        // Show Ad
        showInterstitial();

    }
};
```

then...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the InterstitialAd and set the adUnitId
    mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();
    loadInterstitial();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Start showing Ad in every 60 seconds 
    //when activity is visible to the user
    mHandler = new Handler();
    //mHandler.post(mRunnable);

    // Run first add after 20 seconds
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,20*1000);
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // Stop showing Ad when activity is not visible anymore
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
}

private void loadInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
            .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}

private InterstitialAd newInterstitialAd() {

    InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {

            // Reload ad so it can be ready to be show to the user next time 
            mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();
            loadInterstitial();

        }
    });
    return interstitialAd;

}

private void showInterstitial() {
    // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and reload the ad.
    if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ad did not load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();
        loadInterstitial();
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to show the first ad in 20 seconds and after that after 60 seconds , is that possible ?

Comment: Yes @ChandNinder , just use postDelayed() method from Handler, i just edited the answer, see it in onStart() method... Upvote or Accept the answer as the correct answer if it fulfill your needs :]

Comment: thanks for reply i checked your code and these line are showing in red cant get rid of it 
newInterstitialAd();
    loadInterstitial();

Comment: @ChandNinder these are methods that set up and instantiate your add, i took it from Android Studio project sample "Google  AdMob Ads Activity", i will edit the answer again, see that newInterstitialAd() method is not very different from what you had in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new thread, then add a sleep time of 60000 milliseconds before showing your ad back. It will allow for async working.

Example, add this code in the `onAdClosed()` :

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        Thread.sleep(60000);
        // Show your ad here
    }
}).start();
```